Do I need to configure wal_keep_size or wal_keep_segments when using replication slot?
Do I need to configure wal_keep_size or wal_keep_segments parameters when using replication slot in PostgreSQL? Having only replication sloot ensures the master server keeps the WAL logs required by replicas even when they are disconnected from the master?

There are multiple purposes for which one might want to keep WAL.  Slots satisfy one of those purposes, but don't guarantee there aren't others.  For example, maybe you have multiple replicas and only some of them use slots.

Replication slots alone would suffice for replication process however wal_keep_size is useful if you plan to use pg_rewind to restore the old primary during failover events.
pg_rewind can retrieve WAL segments from the WAL directory or, archive directory if the required WAL is no longer available due to the wal_keep_size limit being exceeded or not set at all. However getting from archive directory requires the restore_command to be configured. Since the archive directory could be in a different location or server, this approach involves slightly more administrative effort compared to using wal_keep_size.
pg_rewind also requires either wal_log_hints or data checksums to be enabled.

A replication slot ensures that the primary server retains the necessary Write-Ahead Logs (WALs) until all connected replicas have confirmed they no longer need them.
Question 1

Do I need to configure wal_keep_size or wal_keep_segments parameters
when using replication slot

Answer 1

No, it is not necessary to configure. The replication slot itself ensures that the necessary WAL files are retained.
You can limit the size of WAL files retained by using this param max_slot_wal_keep_size (default is -1, retain an unlimited amount of WAL files) from Postgres v13.

Question 2

Having only replication slot ensures the master server keeps the WAL logs required by replicas even when they are disconnected from the master?

Answer 2

Yes. By default, with replication slot, in case of disconnection with Slave, Master keeps WAL files until reaching out of disk space on Master.

On production, making sure you monitor the replication slot state and size of WAL files (not going to details)
SELECT * FROM pg_replication_slots;
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_wal_files, pg_size_pretty(SUM(size)) AS total_wal_size FROM pg_ls_waldir();


pg_replication_slots view
pg_ls_waldir() function

